# How to MapPageRoute a folder name to a different one?

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms, asp.net-routing

I'm looking at RouteConfig class or MapPageRoute function adn wonders how do I map the folder name to a different folder name.

Let's say "~/rFolder/foo2/foo.css" and I'm using hte "rFolder" code to map route to "~/Webpages/Folder" which will result in "~/Webpages/Folder/foo2/foo.css" for example.

How can I accomplish this?  Thanks...

```
namespace Dealer.WebApp.Mobile
{
  public class RouteConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "", "~/Webpages/SignIn.aspx");            
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is this what you want ? `routes.MapPageRoute("Foo", "Webpages/Folder", "~/Webpages/Folder/foo2/foo.css");`

Comment: I tried something like this routes.MapPageRoute("route_1","rFolder","~Webpages/Folder"); but it does nothing.   I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET routing.